# Can i Use iTextpdf lib to convert a TIFF to a PNG?

Tags: java, png, itext, tiff

I have TIFF files that contain a single image.
I need to be able to convert them to PNG inside our Java app.
Almost every search says to use JAI - which doesn't seem to exist anymore.

We currently have the itextpdf library in our system, and it looks like it can read a TIFF and write a PNG.

Anyone know how?  Or can point me to the correct section of documentation?
I see that there is a TIFFImage class that looks like it can read a TIFF, and a PNGWriter that can write a PNG - but I haven't been able to figure out how to take the result of the TIFFImage (an Image object) and pass that data to the PNGWriter.

Comment: iText is a library for PDF file creation, manipulation, and analysis. This means that it has a number of classes focused on parsing images from and serializing images to certain bitmap image formats. This does not mean, though, that these functionalities can be employed for bitmap image format conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard ImageIO and my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO TIFF plugin](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) to read the TIFF and write it back as PNG. The plugin can in most cases be used as a direct replacement for the JAI ImageIO TIFF plugin.

When the plugin is installed, your TIFF is single page, and all you care about is the pixel data, the code could simply be:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(tiffFile);
if (!ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", pngFile)) {
    // Handle file not written
}
```

I would not recommend using iText for this (and neither would Bruno Lowagie, it seems). :-)